# Selenium fails button click on www.carmax.com/cars?

Tags: python, selenium, scrape

Any help is appreciated.  New info as of 10.5.2022.

Need help with Selenium trying to scrape list of cars from carmax site.
url = 'https://www.carmax.com/cars?includenontransferables=False&year=2018-2023&mileage=30000&price=18000-30000'

Outside of selenium, I am able submit URL (via Chrome on mac) and then click on "SEE MORE MATCHES" multiple times. It add 22 car tiles each time.   I want to get the full 228 cars that match the filter.

When I use selenium, I get the initial page with list of 22 tiles (cars).
But when I click manually on "SEE MORE MATCHES" (inside Selenium browser) I get the "We're Sorry, an error occured"

So on the selenium browser window I manually pasted the URL and I got a message:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.carmax.com/cars?" on this server.
Reference #18.61f1eb8.1664947333.87596fdb
```

Below is the code I am trying to run to loop thru all the pages to see all 228 car tiles.

```
# The following works and I see a list of cars
# browser = chromedriver()
# browser.get('https://www.carmax.com/cars?includenontransferables=False&year=2018-2023&mileage=30000&price=18000-30000')

# following works because the "SEE MORE MATCHES" @ bottom is display in browser
e = browser.find_element(By.ID, "see-more")
eBut = e.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a")
print(eBut.text)

# The following works because button lights up in blue
hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(eBut)
hover.perform()

# following causes an error "We're sorry, An error occurred in your search."
eBut.click()
time.sleep(3)
```

I check the network log via Chrome log.  When I manually clicks on button... `NOTE visitorID on Request URL`

GOOD REQUEST/RESPONSE on button CLICK

```
> General 
Request URL: https://www.carmax.com/cars/api/search/run?uri=%2Fcars%2Fcrossovers%3Fyear%3D2018-2023%26mileage%3D30000%26price%3D18000-32000&skip=48&take=24&zipCode=76210&radius=radius-nationwide&shipping=-1&sort=lowest-price&scoringProfile=segment_4&visitorID=509f6eb9-eddb-4472-b412-b7e4d73fa263
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [2600:1404:6400:1988::1c4e]:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

> Response Headers
cache-control: public,max-age=120
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 24290
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 06 Oct 2022 03:05:31 GMT
request-context: appId=cid-v1:43e71566-b7e7-4ca6-b692-9f3f68fd9719
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
server-timing: edge; dur=65
server-timing: origin; dur=546
set-cookie: KmxSession_0=SessionId=ef0ffdc3-143d-4dde-9e1c-d16c6ec16e2e&logOdds=0.16263300000000003&logOddsA=-1.103987916&logOddsI=0.8484898; domain=.carmax.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 06-Oct-2022 03:35:31 GMT
set-cookie: KmxVisitor_0=StoreId=6095&Zip=76210&Lat=33.1508&Lon=-97.094&ZipConfirmed=True&ZipDate=10/6/2022 3:05:31 AM&VisitorID=509f6eb9-eddb-4472-b412-b7e4d73fa263&IsFirstVisit=False&UsingStoreProxy=false&AdCode=SEMGAAB&AdCodeDate=10/3/2022 2:54 PM&DistanceShippingTestBucket=2&sRadius=radius-nationwide&LastSearch=638006222940089089&Sort=lowest-price&Shipping=-1; domain=.carmax.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 06-Oct-2023 03:05:31 GMT
set-cookie: bm_sv=A2572EFA5D77E5B9E212CF1F5E3EA1AA~YAAQjDgvF0lum4KDAQAAWV9BqxHO/mA6UGF3uH6Sqq7uQkZArnVAbp5XVaBvnRCWuL1zIgva6mSQmfTX1laMRUXpfsxv1+r/RI7NmAocHADTrGEH5s2EmRWsYB7OXs/nDyx7KiaT+F6qzTLnrAhFKv5hAnT3cfDY2QrducB3BpE3+x/2qCUG7FXEHZZ8Y4vFob+917bdn4LW9rRUjPBvHheQ4eu2Po9mQ8fTtCEQfoTz+em4VRXDYFgmVwWsDpUkeA==~1; Domain=.carmax.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 06 Oct 2022 05:02:07 GMT; Max-Age=6996; Secure
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
timing-allow-origin: *
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-frame-options: sameorigin
x-powered-by: ASP.NE

> REQUEST HEADERS
:authority: www.carmax.com
:method: GET
:path: /cars/api/search/run?uri=%2Fcars%2Fcrossovers%3Fyear%3D2018-2023%26mileage%3D30000%26price%3D18000-32000&skip=48&take=24&zipCode=76210&radius=radius-nationwide&shipping=-1&sort=lowest-price&scoringProfile=segment_4&visitorID=509f6eb9-eddb-4472-b412-b7e4d73fa263
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-type: application/json
cookie: kndctr_0C1038B35278345B0A490D4C_AdobeOrg_identity=CiY2NDEyMjEzMzg1MTI4Njg1NTY5MTUzOTg1ODIwODUzMjcxNzEzN1IOCI-D3PK5MBgBKgNPUjLwAY-D3PK5MA==; _fbp=fb.1.1664808847128.839021144; _gcl_au=1.1.1062470335.1664808847; _gcl_aw=GCL.1664808848.Cj0KCQjwkOqZBhDNARIsAACsbfLBnIzuFAqQwL3--e31KfdmgSD6rJHg3lUTFwSJ8tfceih1AymJoW8aAutBEALw_wcB; _gcl_dc=GCL.1664808848.Cj0KCQjwkOqZBhDNARIsAACsbfLBnIzuFAqQwL3--e31KfdmgSD6rJHg3lUTFwSJ8tfceih1AymJoW8aAutBEALw_wcB; s_fid=7D110C609D492208-3EDD85A763A86C1B; ai_user=e2RLFbYVOZHSuYmJMZxkXo|2022-10-03T14:54:11.532Z; _gid=GA1.2.802830010.1664808852; KmxBestMatch=Bucket=Test; KmxStore=StoreId=6095; at_check=true; AMCVS_0C1038B35278345B0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; s_cc=true; fs_cid=1.0; _clck=vizc8f|1|f5h|0; AKA_A2=A; bm_sz=56BC4464F92D8D3854014390299384A2~YAAQjDgvF0BSm4KDAQAAJkM+qxGtUaRM9kgKs3OhjlPMND6oKDS9L9JrclpSJtoVlcFyP7frV8YD1xCVgcRdw5uFc4++0cxpEv6gpgWh/CigS4uh70WMMwMrSkDHPy2JNGg1vhMIhuwUamy/wLad5DGd71D+cRQicNKzDMPyWJX7e3B4sGONFIQ8VJgq+XW07Y6inJC5kDssxm2FpuI+AqIL/WKcCQ8EWJvk2sXe2r5V8u/oxKUCI3LZ5kcp5dm3m5c2EJ9mSSeGQ34mZPVilnXKDNdt/L5RwAs0lVuW5ogBrSs=~3421507~3224888; KmxSession_0=SessionId=ef0ffdc3-143d-4dde-9e1c-d16c6ec16e2e&logOdds=0.16263300000000003&logOddsA=-1.103987916&logOddsI=0.8484898; bm_mi=F58243EB46DA811B0A46D45132FFFD84~YAAQjDgvF1tSm4KDAQAAJUc+qxGQeUt5Cp1D7OyTa+nWNRnuzi/Ci2BmD4+4Qm0W1sHJA30Ap3m6mceXOzh5wfK03HRe2phSECTcw4RJ5uZBY5eLLkAQpQq3KKGKs0PPcJfrMvauuj9k38zru/2XffC0/Zu/RmhjOvGltYTXUom0lHni/1NId4QNlZH+Dinwy+dQRQsrngcHD/7oF26xgE4ud/TqHYs9HaEeRbP9eypGSng6pEs4oN4gD37JVHz9Uwv1AQaleut5m/tW4BejdCyks9j41mdfB8AqC4+0PlXptnrYyQa5n4cbidpZ7jM=~1; _abck=F2920DB117607824AC32F9ABD87E4CF0~0~YAAQjDgvF3pSm4KDAQAA7kk+qwiI2supb0Wj6jjIVZu5Js77gCQOYAS6Cz5QkS00G8u5W4qQbAInqHTLJ2F54vEUvjFBYsnudLSolWZQ2uSRIOV3FG4VffT+zR2NDBYn+mFGr9Oi0v9ioiaE6xsjOGOwk4UtEc1Y73ft9q9ut4Dl+b1rfqGo1hEUdPSp+Ie2mefY0fFQmhtEJ722KeKJSDg/AmiCQWxrOytVt4V4fLTaDNzByMwQmBxL0GOovHnOo8xxvFpYHV3YE3+nFOBsImR3jPdMqRx833/BKU+EL4g9W87VmtdGBp3/MmBqKBTFJjcx2j59QLbqOHDXG45fLpApfi1ducqf3j9++utrry4yhEQaAr7U3td+W0XHi2xi20UuAyLMuxzwA5iQFMQn1rDlyJhy~-1~-1~1665028912; mbox=PC#40b79aa81c9a40cbaa4d6bda16734a30.35_0#1728270130|session#29f54aa1f68e41e18055c862bd4f0314#1665027190; adobeTransID=9536546868bc6444b2c19840b7ac69c0; s_ppvl=Cars%2C94%2C21%2C3503%2C853%2C805%2C1792%2C1120%2C2%2CP; gpv_v4=Cars; s_visit=1; s_vnc365=1696561330104%26vn%3D7; s_ivc=true; cto_bundle=Lnd0i19yJTJCU3BkWldGeVZGT0lPSkE1dFU1TGJqWE55Q2RBa3BTbUttaHBPWmlGcG5MZyUyQjVOaktVNzQ4eHFndWlBVlVGeiUyQm9HMEVGUWtIeGo2ZzMwWSUyQlh1dXRha2trRGdiaHI5RXZUZHhCJTJCU1Y4SnVYcTl0U3Y5bmtXakFnUjNsVG5jTm42RSUyRlpBSyUyRlpZTGZoeE51UUVXeGk2QzNBcjNPamtoN3gxR25jeFhKSU5qQ2doWTF2eEgxVXFWbllqa2hFbDF6Mg; _uetsid=3a9d8740432b11edb0f42d600c354438; _uetvid=1eca7e007c5911ec859199f79f07ee47; _ga=GA1.1.2103228906.1664808852; fs_uid=#J90WC#5786631356157952:5474652164165632:::#/1687899589; AMCV_0C1038B35278345B0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-1124106680%7CMCMID%7C64122133851286855691539858208532717137%7CMCIDTS%7C19271%7CMCAID%7C304705C596F1394B-6000151B443909A6%7CMCOPTOUT-1665032530s%7CNONE%7CMCAAMLH-1665630130%7C7%7CMCAAMB-1665630130%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI%7CvVersion%7C5.2.0; QSI_HistorySession=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.carmax.com%2Fcars%3Fincludenontransferables%3DFalse%26year%3D2018-2023%26mileage%3D30000%26price%3D18000-30000~1664946926834%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.carmax.com%2Fcars%3Fincludenontransferables%3DFalse%26year%3D2018-2023%26mileage%3D30000%26price%3D18000-32000~1665003893328%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.carmax.com%2Fcars%3Fincludenontransferables%3DFalse%26year%3D2018-2023%26mileage%3D30000%26price%3D18000-30000~1665006891845%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.carmax.com%2Fcars%3Furi%3D%2Fcars%2Fcrossovers%3Fincludenontransferables%3DFalse%26year%3D2018-2023%26mileage%3D30000%26price%3D18000-32000~1665025330891; ak_bmsc=AA0B2B31F438AA727AE20B131E3F04B4~000000000000000000000000000000~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; _clsk=1mpyjk0|1665025366793|3|0|m.clarity.ms/collect; _ga_NTWN6LKPPS=GS1.1.1665025330.7.1.1665025421.0.0.0; ai_session=dwGcZfAd9Et49laIoOjdG+|1665025342556|1665025492736; KmxVisitor_0=StoreId=6095&Zip=76210&Lat=33.1508&Lon=-97.094&ZipConfirmed=True&ZipDate=10/6/2022 3:03:45 AM&VisitorID=509f6eb9-eddb-4472-b412-b7e4d73fa263&IsFirstVisit=False&UsingStoreProxy=false&AdCode=SEMGAAB&AdCodeDate=10/3/2022 2:54 PM&DistanceShippingTestBucket=2&sRadius=radius-nationwide&LastSearch=638006222940089089&Sort=lowest-price&Shipping=-1; bm_sv=A2572EFA5D77E5B9E212CF1F5E3EA1AA~YAAQjDgvFwJpm4KDAQAARsxAqxHE8+frQ64O+0FfncRNlVXCb+PpwuH3zPhQed95YyfQA7k6RmdSdyyRPy28Kh2w0pFvZqpnTi7tuolj+jSUtlS0Za3NunPBLI2e1cXOrd6kwLQ6YMOTBYeRZAvwwUxEFEm4gCa+BKfL6Wh5liEdEVPouU9MEqfK7EYrVfxPXPLNiK4yp40G3fAbZR01Tx+GgmagirDOo9fgoyGa2kjS7dQGnjESxyLKGBG6Dj8ywg==~1; s_ppv=Cars%2C99%2C22%2C9664%2C750%2C805%2C1792%2C1120%2C2%2CL; RT="z=1&dm=carmax.com&si=26ef3d4b-afa7-46e4-bc18-af86a66d0072&ss=l8wh3k9n&sl=4&tt=2jl&bcn=%2F%2F17de4c1c.akstat.io%2F&ld=1tbj&nu=9y8m6cy&cl=413k"; s_sq=carmaxadaptive%3D%2526c.%2526a.%2526activitymap.%2526page%253DCars%2526link%253DSEE%252520MORE%252520MATCHES%2526region%253Dsee-more%2526pageIDType%253D1%2526.activitymap%2526.a%2526.c%2526pid%253DCars%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253Dfunctionzr%252528%252529%25257B%25257D%2526oidt%253D2%2526ot%253DA
referer: https://www.carmax.com/cars/crossovers?year=2018-2023&mileage=30000&price=18000-32000
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove with Options all the hints which indicate that you are an automated bot. They are simply freezing your session when JS verifies these flags. When initializing your bot use the following code and you will be fine,

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options = options)
```

The complete code would be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium
import time
import bs4

# Spawn WebDriver:
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options = options)

# Go-To page:
driver.get("https://www.carmax.com/cars?includenontransferables=false&year=2018-2023&mileage=30000&price=18000-30000")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)

# Click on See More:
ef = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="see-more"]/div/a')))
time.sleep(2)
ef.click()

# Get the Page with Bs4:
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

# Repeat the process...
```

Example of iteration of pages till the end:

```
while True:
    
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="see-more"]/div/a')) > 0:
    
        # Click on See More:
        ef = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="see-more"]/div/a')))
        time.sleep(2)
        ef.click()

        see_more_text = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml").find("span", {"class": "see-more--blue"}).get_text()
        total = int(regex.sub("[^\d+]", '', see_more_text.split(' ')[-1]))
        current = int(regex.sub("[^\d+]", '', see_more_text.split(' ')[0]))
        
        print(f"Status: Currently Viewing {current} of {total} Matches")
    
    else:
        print(f"Status: Currently Viewing {total} of {total} Matches")
        break
```

Comment: This worked for a while... then it stopped working when clicking on button. ???

Comment: Are you sure not to click the button when it is not there or on the last page? Otherwise I would try to leave some time.sleep between clicks in order to better simulate human navigation. This site must be full of checks haha. Anyway, check my latest update.

Comment: I've put sleep times but does not matter.   I even try to manually (via the UI) click on the button and it ends up in forbidden when running with selenium.    Carmax is detecting this is a bot and preventing.  (see new comment)

Comment: @A250, it is very inconsistent.  I changed sleep from 4-7 sec to 10-20 and it worked for a while.   Then stopped.

Comment: It seems when I start selenium, it brings in some environment/profile from previous runs of my program.    @A259 was partially right about increasing the delay but something about the environment caused 1..N runs to fail.   I actually reset my network and restarted my jupyter kernel and then it ran ok.   Also, I noticed that my  Chrome preserves the Carmax zipcode from previous manual runs.    While selenium seems to start with a fresh profile each time.   ( I will research about profiles/cookies w/ selenium ]).

Comment: I tried Tor sessions but are blocked. Using automated vpn switch would be a solution (openVPN) but I would firstly try to clean cookies/cache when using selenium like you said. The clicknium solution is always using a bot therefore unless the lib is wrote very well you will have less probability to adapt the code to the defense system of the target website.

Answer (score 0):

I use another auto lib to solve this problem, it can automate the user browser, not as selenium web driver way.

```
from time import sleep
from clicknium import clicknium as cc

if not cc.chrome.extension.is_installed():
    cc.chrome.extension.install_or_update()

tab = cc.chrome.open("https://www.carmax.com/cars?includenontransferables=false&year=2018-2023")

tab.wait_appear_by_xpath('//*[@id="see-more"]/div/div/span[1]', wait_timeout=5)
while tab.is_existing_by_xpath('//*[@id="see-more"]/div/a'):
    tab.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="see-more"]/div/a').click()
    sleep(3)
```

Comment: Tks for the comment... at this time I am very vested in selenium... may try this if not working in couple of days